# How would I parse my date into the mm/dd/yy format?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to be able to parse this date-time format "2011-12-02T16:18:12.479-05:00" into an mm/dd/yy format. What is the best way to do that? I am trying to do -

```
final DateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
final DateFormat dateFormatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM d, yyyy");
String timestamp = dateFormatOut.format(dateFormatIn.parse(someDate);
```

But I get an exception 'java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-12-02T16:18:12.479-05:00"' Any insights into what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input date `2011-12-02T16:18:12.479-05:00` contains milliseconds. 
Use the following instead

```
final DateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is because of the ' marks around `Z`.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ");
```

Wrote up a quick script to test it. Works fine now.

Comment: Hehe, I had to run it again to double check that it worked with only the 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
final DateFormat dateFormatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, joda-time [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty awesome time utility library that would make date formatting pretty straightforward. There are a few tutorials, as well as APIs, on their site. As for your ParseException, I believe that the answers above should be helpful :)